# Where is appcfg.py in google-cloud-sdk-133.0.0-darwin-x86_64.tar.gz?

Tags: eclipse, python-2.7, google-app-engine, pydev

I'm trying to setup Eclipse to run PyDev to develop for GAE and I can't figure out to to link to the interpreter.

I'm linking to Google App engine directory,  google-cloud-sdk/  folder that contains the /lib but I'm getting an error:

```
 Invalid Google App Engine directory. Did not find: appcfg.py in /Users/bryanwheelock/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk
```

I ran Find command on the computer and couldn't find any instances of appcfg.py

Was is left out of the package?

Comment: This is where I have it: `google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/appcfg.py`  I'm at 131.0.0.

Comment: For some reason google_appengine wasn't included in the google-cloud-sdk package I downloaded.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After an install of the SDK, it is easiest to add components and update on the command line.  If you are missing GAE files, then try this:

```
gcloud components install app-engine-python
```

To later upgrade, do this:

```
gcloud components update
```

I suspect that the tar.gz file you downloaded intentionally does not include all components because most people don't need all components and it just adds bloat.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure app-engine-python is first installed.

```
gcloud components list


Your current Cloud SDK version is: 134.0.0
The latest available version is: 134.0.0

┌─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                                                  Components                                                 │
├───────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────────┬──────────────────────────┬───────────┤
│     Status    │                         Name                         │            ID            │    Size   │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────┼───────────┤
│ Not Installed │ App Engine Go Extensions                             │ app-engine-go            │  47.2 MiB │
│ Not Installed │ Cloud Datastore Emulator (Legacy)                    │ gcd-emulator             │  38.1 MiB │
│ Not Installed │ Cloud Pub/Sub Emulator                               │ pubsub-emulator          │  16.3 MiB │
│ Not Installed │ Google Container Registry's Docker credential helper │ docker-credential-gcr    │   2.2 MiB │
│ Not Installed │ gcloud Alpha Commands                                │ alpha                    │   < 1 MiB │
│ Not Installed │ gcloud Beta Commands                                 │ beta                     │   < 1 MiB │
│ Not Installed │ gcloud app Java Extensions                           │ app-engine-java          │ 124.4 MiB │
│ Not Installed │ gcloud app PHP Extensions (Mac OS X)                 │ app-engine-php-darwin    │  21.9 MiB │
│ Not Installed │ kubectl                                              │ kubectl                  │  14.0 MiB │
│ Installed     │ BigQuery Command Line Tool                           │ bq                       │   < 1 MiB │
│ Installed     │ Cloud Datastore Emulator                             │ cloud-datastore-emulator │  15.4 MiB │
│ Installed     │ Cloud SDK Core Libraries                             │ core                     │   5.1 MiB │
│ Installed     │ Cloud Storage Command Line Tool                      │ gsutil                   │   2.8 MiB │
│ Installed     │ Default set of gcloud commands                       │ gcloud                   │           │
│ Installed     │ gcloud app Python Extensions                         │ app-engine-python        │   7.2 MiB │
└───────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────┴──────────────────────────┴───────────┘
```

appcfg.py is located under,

```
<google-cloud-sdk>/platform/google_appengine/
```

Use this URL in pydev for GAE directory.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check here?

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine
```

Comment: This should be a comment not an answer